# XAML Designer error: "IOException: Cannot locate resource" - How to provide a Pack URI that works with dynamic assembly name?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

We have a `ResourceDictionary` being referenced as follows

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Theming/AppTheme.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

This works great at runtime. However, the Designer in Visual Studio gives an error in views that reference this UserControl:

> IOException: Cannot locate resource 'theming/apptheme.xaml'.

Other SO answers have suggested referencing the ResourceDictionary by specifying the assembly name:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyDomain.MyApp.Wpf;component/Theming/AppTheme.xaml" />
```

This makes the Designer happy, but our assembly name is different in staging vs. production, so it would be nice if we didn't have to specify the assembly name. My question is: **How can we provide a ResourceDictionary Source URI that makes the Designer happy and does not require specifying the assembly name?**

If this is not possible, we might make the URI a static value that is different per build configuration using preprocessor directives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the UI or resources for your app using XAML.
Resources are typically definitions of some object that you expect to use more than once. To refer to a XAML resource later, you specify a key for a resource that acts like its name.
You can reference a resource throughout an app or from any XAML page within it.
You can define your resources using a ResourceDictionary element from the Windows Runtime XAML.
Then, you can reference your resources by using a StaticResource markup extension or ThemeResource markup extension.

Resources don't have to be strings.
they can be any shareable object, such as styles, templates, brushes, and colors. However, controls, shapes, and other FrameworkElements are not shareable, so they can't be declared as reusable resources.

Example:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <x:String x:Key="key1">Hey</x:String>
    <x:String x:Key="key2">Nice</x:String>
</Page.Resources>
```

you can use those resoures by addressing the keys in their proper location i.e.:

```
<Label Text="{StaticResource key1}" FontSize="Large" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Well, In order to make your project more organized you need to make a ResourceDictionary a seperate file and call it like this (ContentPage part is depending on the page):

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

// in this example Styles is in the same folder has the page you can make dynamic resource to access it from all areas or make a path in a proper manner like:

```
xmlns:themes = "clr-namespace:AppName.Themes;assembly=AppName"
```

How can we provide a ResourceDictionary Source URI that makes the Designer happy and does not require specifying the assembly name?
you make a dynamic one.
like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ResourceDictionary
    x:Class="App.Themes.Theme"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
<Color x:Key="PrimaryColor">#ffffff</Color>
<Color x:Key="PrimaryDarkColor">#0f0f0f</Color>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and in app.xaml you do this (if Theme is in folder Themes in main project):

```
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:themes = "clr-namespace:YourProjectName.Themes;assembly=YourProjectName"
             x:Class="YourProjectName.App">

    <Application.Resources>

    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <themes:Theme />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries >
    </ResourceDictionary>

</Application.Resources>
```

then you can do stuff like this anywhere:

```
    BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PrimaryColor}"
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks, this worked! However, I'll add that I needed to make a code-behind class inheriting from `ResourceDictionary` and set the xaml build action to `Page` to satisfy the compiler.